# Reasons for inconsistent VB.NET syntax?

Tags: vb.net, syntax

Does anyone know if there's any particular reason that VB.NET construct syntax isn't consistent? For example:

```
If
...
End If

Select
...
End Select
```

You'd assume it would be `for... end for`, `while... end while` ... but instead we have:

```
While
...
Wend

For
...
Next
```

This has mildly frustrated me for a while, and I just got to wondering whether there was any conscious decision behind it. Or was it just an initial not-so-well-thought-out design decision that can no longer be changed because of backwards compatibility problems?

Comment: I thought it was While ... End While or Do While ... Loop. With the For .. Next syntax it could just be that it has been that way traditionally with basic.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, it's `End While` since VB 7. The `Do ... Loop` construct is however another example of the inconsistency. To be consistent it would be `Loop ... End Loop`, however `End Loop Until ...` doesn't make sense semantically.

Comment: It kind of makes sense as it can be `Do While ... Loop` or `Do ... Loop While`

Comment: @Chris, @Guffa It can also be `Do Until ... Loop` or `Do ... Loop Until` or even an infinite loop `Do ... Loop`. It's a flexible loop syntax that's similar to written English: although admittedly it's not 100% consistent with `End If` and `End Select`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `While` construct has actually gotten more consistent since VB 7. It's now `End While` instead of `Wend`.

The reason for the inconsistent `Next` is mostly historical. It's been that way in BASIC since the first version, more than 40 years ago.

Comment: @froadie: No, if it was deprecated it would still work, it's simply replaced. The compiler still regognises it though, and if you try to use it you get a specific error message that it's replaced.

Answer (score 3):

In older versions, the `Next` keyword required a variable name (eg, `Next n`).

It wouldn't make sense to write `End For n`.

Comment: I still put the variable if I'm nesting loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while/end while.

For/next makes sense to me, but that may be because I'm used to it.

These language terms have been in use in several older variants of Basic for years.  I assume that is why MS chose to use them.